# How can I save my refence when it is always thrown off the list?

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2019

As I want to add the reference Microsoft.VisualBasic in Visual Studio 2019, the reference appears with a yellow warning. Always I go into the reference manager, the reference Microsoft.VisualBasic isn't ticked. What can I do? (I'm using .NET-Framework 4.8)
Thanks!

Comment: What functions are you using in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly?  There are generally better and more modern packages you should be using.

Comment: Are you using VB.Net which is a managed library.  Microsoft.VisualBasic is not managed so you cannot add as a reference.

Comment: The problem is now solved: I only had to build the project and then it worked. I wanted to use the Input-Box but then I created my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A yellow exclamation mark usually occurs if target framework of destination project is different and the version of references was different. Or this reference is not available.

You can follow the steps below;

- Remove your `Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference.
- Right click on the solution name, `clean` it and close VS.
- Go to the root folder, delete the `.vs` folder.
- Delete the `obj` folder in the project .
- Open your project again and add the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference to your project under Reference Manager> Assemblies.

If the problem still persists, open the `.csproj` file of your project with a notepad or similar tool and check if the reference under ItemGroup is correctly.

For more information, you can check out the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/wkze6zky(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).